# ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 error when downloading files from Podio with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, download, podio

I am trying to download files from Podio using Ruby Rails and am using the example from the bottom of this page: https://developers.podio.com/examples/files.

It shows the following Ruby code..

```
File.open('/tmp/downloaded_file', 'w') do |downloaded_file|
  file = Podio::FileAttachment.find(42)
  downloaded_file.write(file.raw_data)
end
```

When trying to download I get the following error for any type of file (word, powerpoint, excel):

```
The task failed because of an error: "\xBC" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
```

I then try to get around this problem by changing the one line to:

```
downloaded_file.write(file.raw_data.force_encoding('UTF-8'))
```

It will now download the file but they are corrupted. Powerpoints, Excel and Word documents will not open.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try `wb` instead `w` in your `File.open` command? (wb = write binary). As an alternative, try `w:ASCII-8BIT`.

Comment: Which version of Ruby are you using?